# How to change element name while loading data with Record Loader?

Tags: marklogic

I have the following xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<patent-assignment>
  <assignment-record>
    <correspondent>
      <name>NORTH AMERICA INTERNATIONAL PATENT OFFIC</name>
      <address-1>P.O. BOX 506</address-1>
      <address-2>MERRIFIELD, VA 22116</address-2>
    </correspondent>
   </assignment-record>
  <patent-assignors>
    <patent-assignor>
      <name>TSAI, YU-WEN</name>
      <execution-date>
    <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
    <patent-assignor>
      <name>HUANG, CHENG-I</name>
      <execution-date>
    <date>20050331</date>
      </execution-date>
    </patent-assignor>
  </patent-assignors>
  <patent-assignees>
    <patent-assignee>
      <name>FARADAY TECHNOLOGY CORP.</name>
      <address-1>NO.10-2, LI-HSIN ROAD 1, SCIENCE-BASED INDUSTRIAL PARK</address-1>
      <city>HSIN-CHU CITY</city>
      <country-name>TAIWAN</country-name>
    </patent-assignee>
  </patent-assignees>
 </patent-assignment>
```

Now at the time of loading document into Marklogic I want to change patent-assignor's element name to assignor-name and patent-assignee's element name to assignee-name but I want to load data with Record Loader not with Marklogic's Information Studio. How can I do this with Record Loader ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to set `CONTENT_FACTORY_CLASSNAME=com.marklogic.recordloader.xcc.XccModuleContentFactory` and write an XQuery module to implement the content module. There is an example module at http://marklogic.github.com/recordloader/ which you can customize. Your transform code would go in the `local:do()` function, replacing the example "lower-case element localnames" code:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare variable $URI as xs:string external;
declare variable $XML-STRING as xs:string external;
declare variable $NAMESPACE as xs:string external;
declare variable $LANGUAGE as xs:string external;
declare variable $ROLES-EXECUTE as xs:string external;
declare variable $ROLES-INSERT as xs:string external;
declare variable $ROLES-READ as xs:string external;
declare variable $ROLES-UPDATE as xs:string external;
declare variable $COLLECTIONS as xs:string external;
declare variable $SKIP-EXISTING as xs:boolean external;
declare variable $ERROR-EXISTING as xs:boolean external;
declare variable $FORESTS as xs:string external;

declare function local:do($list as node()*)
 as node()*
{
  for $n in $list return typeswitch($n)
  (: lower-case element localnames :)
  case element() return element {
    QName(namespace-uri($n), lower-case(local-name($n)))
  } {
    $n/@*, local:do($n/node())
  }
  case document-node() return document { local:do($n/node()) }
  default return $n
};

if ($SKIP-EXISTING and doc($URI)) then ()
else if ($ERROR-EXISTING and doc($URI)) then error((), 'DUPLICATE-URI', $URI)
else xdmp:document-insert(
  $URI,
  local:do(xdmp:unquote(
    $XML-STRING,
    $NAMESPACE,
    if ($LANGUAGE) then concat('default-language=', $LANGUAGE) else ()
  )),
  (
    for $r in tokenize($ROLES-EXECUTE, ',')[. ne '']
    return xdmp:permission('execute', $r),
    for $r in tokenize($ROLES-INSERT, ',')[. ne '']
    return xdmp:permission('insert', $r),
    for $r in tokenize($ROLES-READ, ',')[. ne '']
    return xdmp:permission('read', $r),
    for $r in tokenize($ROLES-UPDATE, ',')[. ne '']
    return xdmp:permission('update', $r)
  ),
  tokenize($COLLECTIONS, ',')[. ne ''],
  0,
  for $id in tokenize($FORESTS, ',')[. ne '']
  return xs:unsignedLong($id)
)
```